# Hello , i wanted to print the cordinates of a point using classes in c++ but i have a problem

Tags: c++, point

So i found the distance between the two points , but i also wanted two show the cordinates of the point . The code shows no errors but when i run it the print funciton doesent show the cordinates I wanted but just the distance of the two points is shown. The code is represented below, and also the output.
[image: The output looks like this]

```
class Point {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x, int  y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    double distance(Point other) {
        return sqrt(pow(x - other.x, 2) + pow(y - other.y, 2));
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Point cordinates " << "(" << x << "," << y << ")"; // Form (x,y)- example (4,3)    
    }
};

int main() {
    Point obj1 = Point(3, 4);
    Point obj2 = Point(4, 3);
    cout << "Distance between two points : " << obj1.distance(obj2);
    cout << endl;
    void print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void print();` is a function declaration. It does not call a print() function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you are calling `print` on an instance of `Print`.

```
p = Point(1, 2);
p.print();
```

However, there are a couple more things that can be pointed out.

First is using initializer lists with constructors.

```
class Point {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x_init, int y_init) : x(x_init), y(y_init) { }
```

Secondly, the idiomatic way of printing an instance to an output stream is to overload `<<` for your type.

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x_init, int y_init) : x(x_init), y(y_init) { }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Point& p);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, Point& p) {
    return o << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")";
}

int main() {
    Point p(3, 4);

    std::cout << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Third, your `distance` function does not mutate the object, so should probably be tagged as `const`.

```
    double distance(Point other) const {
        return sqrt(pow(x - other.x, 2) + pow(y - other.y, 2));
    }
```